# Java program that reads user input until 0 is entered, also makes a few calculations (evens/odds, average, etc.)

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

This program is meant to take user input until a zero is entered, and then print out information on the integers. It's also meant to read if the input in even/odd, calculate the sum, find the largest and smallest entered integers, tally the total integers entered, and find the average. It won't stop when the user enters 0, and it won't print the "No data entered" line if there's no input. It also isn't figuring even numbers properly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int counter = 0;
    double even = 0;
    double odd = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    int input = 0;
    int large = 0;
    int small = 0;
    double average;

    System.out.print("Enter a series of values (0 to quit): ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while ((input = in.nextInt()) != 0) {

        small = in.nextInt();
        large = in.nextInt();

        if (input != 0)
            sum = input + sum;
            counter++;

        if (input > large)
            large = input;

        if (input < small)
            small = input;

        if (input % 2 == 0)
            even = even + 1;
        else
            odd = odd + 1;

        }

    if (counter > 0) {

        average = sum / counter;

        System.out.println("The smallest integer is: " + small);
        System.out.println("The largest integer is: " + large);
        System.out.println("Total number of integers entered is " + counter);
        System.out.println("Total even numbers entered is " + even);
        System.out.println("Total odd numbers entered is " + odd);
        System.out.println("The average value is: " + average);
    } else {

            System.out.println("No data was entered.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't "run successfully" if it doesn't do what you expect.  Step through the code, examine variables at each statement and find where it deviates from what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading the first numbers to populate large and small we only need to do that once. And without re-reading the numbers with `in.nextInt()` because that will eat up the next inputs that are entered, which was probably causing the not terminating at zero error.

```
while ((input = in.nextInt()) != 0) {

        if (counter == 0)
          small = large = input;

        if (input != 0)
            sum = input + sum;
            counter++;

        if (input > large)
            large = input;

        if (input < small)
            small = input;

        if (input % 2 == 0)
            even = even + 1;
        else
            odd = odd + 1;

        }
```

Comment: There is no need to retest `input !=0` **in** the loop (the loop condition tests that); adding whitespace to `counter++` doesn't put in the `if (input != 0)` test either (not that that matters here), and using braces is to (almost) always be encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You are inputting extra numbers in the loop body for `large` and `small`. Use `++` instead of `+= 1`, I would prefer `Integer.min` and `Integer.max`; initialize `small` and `large` to something very large and very small respectively. Something like,

```
double even = 0, odd = 0, sum = 0;
int counter = 0, input = 0, large = Integer.MIN_VALUE, small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.print("Enter a series of values (0 to quit): ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while ((input = in.nextInt()) != 0) {
    small = Integer.min(small, input);
    large = Integer.max(large, input);
    sum += input;
    counter++;
    if (input % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
    } else {
        odd++;
    }
}

if (counter > 0) {
    double average = sum / counter;
    System.out.println("The smallest integer is: " + small);
    System.out.println("The largest integer is: " + large);
    System.out.println("Total number of integers entered is " + counter);
    System.out.println("Total even numbers entered is " + even);
    System.out.println("Total odd numbers entered is " + odd);
    System.out.println("The average value is: " + average);
} else {
    System.out.println("No data was entered.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WAP to input a number and check ut is even ir odd until user user input is zero using infinite for loop.
Using format:
for(;;)
{
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Take integer inputs till the user enters 0 and print the sum of all numbers (HINT: while loop)

        int n =1;
        int x = 0;

        while (n !=0){
            

            n= input.nextInt();

            x+=n;

        }
        System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.dev.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// code for Take integer inputs till the user enters 0 and print the largest number from all
        

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the nuumber: ");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        
        int max = 0;
        
        while(true) {
            if(a>0) {
                if(a>max)
                    max = a;
                
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
            
            a = in.nextInt();
        }
        
        System.out.println("The largest number of all is "+ max);
        
    }
                

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LargestTill0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter no: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        int lar = 0;
        while(num != 0){
            if (num > lar){
                lar = num;
            }
            System.out.print("enter no: ");
            num = in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("largest number is: " + lar);
    }
}
```